# Problema de declaración de atributo

Tags: python, python-3.x

Tengo estas dos líneas dentro de una class llamada Scalar (define magnitudes escalares de forma básica), una literalmente al lado de la otra:

```
self.__range = (0, 0)
print(self.__range)
```

Las ubiqué a modo de prueba al principio del method **init** de la class.
La class la llamo desde otro documento usando:

```
import Scalar as sc
# ... código que funciona
days = float(input('Ingrese la cantidad de días: '))
dias = sc.Scalar(amount=days, symbol='dias')
# ... Más código similar a este o que funciona
```

Al darle F5 en Atom me tira:

```
AttributeError: 'Scalar' object has no attribute '_Scalar__range'
```

Y no entiendo por qué. Todo el resto del programa funciona. Uso PyFlakes y PyCodeStyle y tengo 0 (cero) errores. Las dos líneas las probé en varias partes de la class, y lo mismo. Sé que debe ser algo muy elemental pero sinceramente me quedé sin ideas. Agradezco el tiempo de antemano.
P.D.: Ya probé renombrar, y probé desencapsular, y mismo error.

Edit: Agrego todo el código del módulo. El error ocurre en línea 117 al printear. En método **init** hay dos líneas de prueba (86 y 87) que tampoco me permite ejecutar

```
def super_isinstance(var, *args,):
    if len(args) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        table_of_truth = []
        for i in range(len(args)):
            if (args[i] not in ('int', 'float', 'complex', 'bool',
                                'str', 'list', 'tuple')):
                return False
        else:
            for i in args:
                table_of_truth.append(string_isinstance(var, i))
            else:
                if True in table_of_truth:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False


def string_isinstance(var, i,):
    if i == 'int':
        return isinstance(var, int)
    elif i == 'float':
        return isinstance(var, float)
    elif i == 'complex':
        return isinstance(var, complex)
    elif i == 'bool':
        return isinstance(var, bool)
    elif i == 'str':
        return isinstance(var, str)
    elif i == 'list':
        return isinstance(var, list)
    elif i == 'tuple':
        return isinstance(var, tuple)


class UnitTypes:
    def __init__(self,):
        self.__activity = {'extensive', 'intensive'}
        self.__magnitude = {'escalar', 'vectorial'}
        self.__unc = ' +/-'
        self.__prefixes = {
                            ('Y', 'yotta', 1E24),
                            ('Z', 'zetta', 1E21),
                            ('E', 'exa', 1E18),
                            ('P', 'peta', 1E15),
                            ('T', 'tera', 1E12),
                            ('G', 'giga', 1E9),
                            ('M', 'mega', 1E6),
                            ('k', 'kilo', 1E3),
                            ('h', 'hecto', 1E2),
                            ('da', 'deca', 1E1),
                            ('d', 'deci', 1E-1),
                            ('c', 'centi', 1E-2),
                            ('m', 'mili', 1E-3),
                            ('µ', 'micro', 1E-6),
                            ('n', 'nano', 1E-9),
                            ('p', 'pico', 1E-12),
                            ('f', 'femto', 1E-15),
                            ('a', 'atto', 1E-18),
                            ('z', 'zepto', 1E-21),
                            ('y', 'yocto', 1E-24),
                          }

    def rt_act(self,):
        return self.__activity

    def rt_mag(self,):
        return self.__magnitude

    def s_unc(self,):
        return self.__unc

    def rt_pfx(self,):
        return self.__prefixes


ut = UnitTypes()


class Scalar:
    def __init__(self, name='Scalar', range=(0, 0), df_amount=0,
                 df_symbol='', df_uncertainty=0,
                 *, amount, symbol, uncertainty=0.0):

        self.fromx_to_toy = (0, 0)
        print(self.fromx_to_toy)
        self.__range_checking(range)  # Llama a Range
        if self.__in_range(amount, uncertainty):
            self.__am = amount
            self.__unc = uncertainty
        elif self.__in_range(amount, df_uncertainty):
            self.__am = amount
            self.__unc = df_uncertainty
        else:
            self.__am = df_amount
            self.__unc = df_uncertainty
        self.__sy = symbol
        self.__name_checking(name)
        return

    def __range_checking(self, g_range,):
        print(isinstance(g_range, tuple))
        print(len(g_range) == 2)
        print(super_isinstance(g_range[1], 'int', 'float'))
        print(super_isinstance(g_range[0], 'int', 'float'))
        print(g_range[0] != g_range[1])
        if (isinstance(g_range, tuple) and len(g_range) == 2
            and super_isinstance(g_range[0], 'int', 'float')
            and super_isinstance(g_range[1], 'int', 'float')
                and g_range[0] != g_range[1]):
            print('isinstance ok')
            self.__range = (min(g_range[0], g_range[1]),
                            max(g_range[1], g_range[0]))
        else:
            self.__range = (0, 0)
            print(self.__range)
        return

    def __name_checking(self, name,):
        if name.isidentifier():
            self.__name = name
        else:
            self.__name = 'Scalar'

    def __in_range(self, value, uncertainty=0):
        if self.__range == (0, 0):
            return True
        else:
            value_plus_u = value + abs(uncertainty)
            value_minus_u = value - abs(uncertainty)
            if self.__range[0] <= value_plus_u <= self.__range[1]:
                if self.__range[0] <= value_minus_u <= self.__range[1]:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
            else:
                return False

    def __str__(self,):
        if self.__unc != 0:
            return f'{self.__am} {self.__sy}{ut.s_unc()}{self.__unc}' +\
                   f'{self.__sy}'
        else:
            return f'{self.__am} {self.__sy}'

    def amt(self,):
        return self.__am

    def sym(self,):
        return self.__sy

    def uct(self,):
        return self.__unc

    def data(self):
        if self.__range == (0, 0):
            print(f'Nombre: {self.__name}\nRango: No\n'
                  f'Unidad: {self.__sy}')
        else:
            print(f'Nombre: {self.__name}\nRango: {self.__range}\n'
                  f'Unidad: {self.__sy}')

    def __add__(self, other):
        if (self.sym() == other.sym()
                and self.__in_range(self.__am + other.amt())):
            return self.__am + other.amt()
        else:
            return self.__am

    def _iadd__(self, other):
        if (self.sym() == other.sym()
                and self.__in_range(self.__am
                                    + other.amt(), self.__unc + self.__uct)):
            self.__am += other.amt()
            self.__unc += other.uct()

    def __sub__(self, other):
        if (self.sym() == other.sym()
                and self.__in_range(self.__am - other.amt())):
            return self.__am - self.amt()
        else:
            return self.__am

    def __isub__(self, other):
        if (self.sym() == other.sym()
                and self.__in_range(self.__am
                                    - other.amt(), self.__unc + self.__uct)):
            self.__am -= other.amt()
            self.__unc += other.uct()

    def __lt__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am < other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __le__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am <= other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __eq__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am == other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __ne__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am != other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __gt__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am > other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __ge__(self, other):
        if self.sym() == other.sym() and self.__am >= other.amt():
            return True
        else:
            return False

    def __int__(self):
        return int(self.__am)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'force_value' and super_isinstance(value, 'int', 'float'):
            if self.__in_range(value):
                self.__am = value
        elif name == 'uncertainty' and super_isinstance(value, 'int', 'float'):
            if self.__in_range(self.__am, value):
                self.__unc = value
        elif name == 'set_range' and isinstance(value, tuple):
            self.__range_checking(value)
        elif name == 'force_symbol' and isinstance(value, str):
            self.__sy = value


dias = Scalar(amount=20.0, symbol='Holas')
```

Comment: Los nombres de atributo que comienzan por __ son tratados de forma especial por python para dificultar el que se pueda accder a ellos desde fuera del objeto, lo mas parecido a un atributo "protegido" que python puede ofrecer. Cambia el nombre para que no empiece por __. Por ejemplo, un solo _.

Comment: No obstante lo dicho anteriormente, desde el propio objeto sí debería dejarte, es decir lo de `self.__range` no debería dar problema en un método de la clase `Scalar`. ¿Estás seguro de que sólo intentas acceder a `__range` vía `self`? Fíjate bien en qué línea te tira el error y edita la pregunta para poner más contexto (más código) si hace falta. Esto funciona --> https://repl.it/repls/FuchsiaCruelLaboratory#main.py ¿en qué se diferencia esto de lo tuyo?

Comment: Acabé de renombrar y desencapsular al tupla:
Quedando algo como
'self.fromx_to_toy = (0, 0)
print(self.fromx_to_toy)'
y me sigue tirando el mismo error. Por lo que ahora sí que no sé cual es el problema.

Comment: Acá tenés todo el código por si querés o alguien quiere revisar. https://repl.it/repls/PushyTreasuredComputerscience#main.py. La prueba hecha está en la linea 90 y donde está el code en sí es la línea 119

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Básicamente el problema que estamos encontrando es que tras definir un atributo en el objeto, intentamos mostrarlo:

```
self.atributo = (0,0)
print(self.atributo)
```

y se produce el error de que el objeto no tiene ese `atributo` (y esto para cualquier nombre de atributo que se prueba).

La solución al misterio se encuentra al estudiar el código completo de la clase `Scalar` y observar que tiene un método llamado `__setattr__()`.

Este método forma parte del *modelo de datos python*, y es invocado automáticamente cada vez que se intenta asignar un valor a un atributo del objeto. Es decir, que la línea:

```
self.atributo = (0,0)
```

en realidad está produciendo la siguiente invocación:

```
self.__setattr__('atributo', (0,0))
```

Y si miramos cómo está implementado este método encontramos:

```
    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        if name == 'force_value' and super_isinstance(value, 'int', 'float'):
            if self.__in_range(value):
                self.__am = value
        elif name == 'uncertainty' and super_isinstance(value, 'int', 'float'):
            if self.__in_range(self.__am, value):
                self.__unc = value
        elif name == 'set_range' and isinstance(value, tuple):
            self.__range_checking(value)
        elif name == 'force_symbol' and isinstance(value, str):
            self.__sy = value
```

Desconozco la razón exacta por la que lo has implementado de este modo (posiblemente sería más limpio y legible usar decoradores `@property`, y escribir *setters*, si lo que quieres es validar las asignaciones). En cualquier caso lo que ocurre es que, al no ser el nombre de atributo ninguno de los especificados en los `if ... elif`, no se ejecuta ninguna de las aisgnaciones, por lo que al final el atributo queda sin definir. Así que no es de extrañar que luego el `print()` falle.

Aparte de reconsiderar el diseño, de momento una solución podría ser añadir la siguiente línea al final de `__setattr__()`:

```
        else:
            super().__setattr__(name, value)
```

De este modo, si el atributo que se intenta asignar no encaja con ninguno de los anteriores, se hace una asignación "normal", sin validar.

## ¡Cuidado!

Observa que tu implementación de `__setattr__()` encerraba otra trampa.

Si el nombre del atributo que intentas asignar es uno de los previstos, por ejemplo `self.force_symbol = "foo"`, entonces sí que entraría por este `elif`:

```
        elif name == 'force_symbol' and isinstance(value, str):
            self.__sy = value
```

con lo que llegaría al intento de asignación `self.__sy = value` ¡que causaría una llamada recursiva a `self.__setattr__('__sy', value)`!!

Esta llamada recursiva típicamente causa un bucle de recursión infinito que acaba por romper el programa, pero no en tu caso porque al no estar el nombre `__sy` en ninguno de los casos que contemplas, le pasaría como al `atributo` de antes, quedaría sin asignar.

En definitiva, tal como lo tenías, era imposible asignarle ningún atributo a tu objeto, ya sea porque el atributo no era ninguno de los previstos, ya porque cuando sí era uno de los previstos al final recursivamente intentabas asignar otro, que también quedaría sin asignar.

Con el apaño que te propongo, esa llamada recursiva se resolvería al entrar por el `else:` final. Pero todo ello es bastante enrevesado y un poco chapucero. El código es farragoso y proclive a errores, por la mezcla de atributos con nombre "especial" y además el uso de `__setattr__()`.

Quizás si explicases qué pretendes se podría sugerir alguna alternativa más "limpia".

Comment: Qué tal. Agradezco infinitamente tu respuesta. Mi objetivo es mantener el encapsulado lo más estricto posible, y modificar los atributos de forma indirecta. Sinceramente hablando, no entendí algunas cosas de tu respuesta jajaja. Creo que entendí lo de __setattr__ y por ende lo tengo que remover. Hice exactamente lo mismo que recién pero empleando __call__ (ya que no tengo pensado usarlo para otra cosa), así no me meto en el modelo de datos. Me falta muchísimo evidentemente, gracias por notarlo. Un saludo y vuelvo a agradecer la dedicación en responderme.

Comment: @Py-Yesod Entiendo. Creo que el decorador `@property` y los _setter_ es justo lo que necesitas. [Aqui](https://repl.it/join/iipnfrzf-abul4fia) te dejo un ejemplo que reimplementa tu código usando ese enfoque. La función `__setaddr__()` ha sido eliminada y el acceso a las propiedades "internas" se controla con los setter y getters. De todas formas yo no me obsesionaría mucho con la encapsulación en Python. Denota que vienes del java :-) Al final quien se lo proponga podrá acceder a las propiedades "internas"

Comment: Jajajjajaj no vengo de Java. Recién estoy empezando a programar (debo tener unas 20 hs en python). De chico debo tener unas 100 hs de C (exagerando), pero recién ahora estoy "aprendiendo" lo que sería OOP. Lo que busco en realidad es hacerme buenos hábitos de programación conforme voy aprendiendo. Con lo que me acabaste de enseñar CLARAMENTE el código es más clean y se entiende mejor, que es mi objetivo. Muchas gracias! Voy 2 preguntas y las 2 me las contestaste vos, así que asumo que vamos a seguir intercambiando palabras. Te mando un saludo!